# adal-angular4 throwing warnings in angular 5 project

Tags: angular, adal, angular5

I recently installed adal-angular4 for some active directory login stuff, but after a basic implementation I am getting these warnings on startup. I don't really know how to debug / address the warning.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/adal-angular4/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
5675:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
    at ImportLazyContextDependency.getWarnings (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\ContextDependency.js:39:18)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:703:24)
    at Compilation.finish (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:561:9)
    at applyPluginsParallel.err (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:506:17)
    at C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:289:11
    at C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\index.js:60:9
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\Documents\FWDS\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:666:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:639:5)
 @ ./node_modules/adal-angular4/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
 @ ./node_modules/adal-angular4/adal4-interceptor.js
 @ ./node_modules/adal-angular4/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

Here is what my package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "fwds",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "adal-angular4": "^1.1.10",
    "angular-timeline": "^1.7.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "tedious": "^2.1.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-timeline": "^1.7.0",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 1.5.0.",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "myURL.com"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": ""
}
```

I don't know what is causing it, I didn't modify any of the adal-angular stuff, perhaps I am missing a dependency?

If you have any insight let me know, thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your `package.json` file?

Comment: Yeah that might of been helpful, just added it

Comment: You can try the workaround mentioned in [a comment by @Codefearingguy](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4/issues/26).

Comment: we're also facing this issue. seems that the git suggestions we implement are not successful.

Comment: @bob.mazzo sadly in the month between this post and now we still have yet to find a solution :/

Answer (score 0):

If anybody still has this issue, the solution as suggested [here](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4/blob/master/README.md) would be to use 2.x.x for Angular 5 projects and 3.x.x for angular 6 projects.